# REST API. Sending sensitive data in URL . Security issue

Tags: apex, security, url

I have a security issue. I built an app that interacts with WordPress and its plugins via REST api, gets and posts some info and syncs it with Salesforce data. I have apex classes that perform HTTP GET, POST, and PUT requests. As I submitted the app for the Security Review it failed with the annotation that  long lasting access tokens and API tokens must not be sent in URLs. What alternatives can be used in this case? What are the most suitable to use in apex and Salesforce?

Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: Please provide more details and/or a code example of how you're currently managing authorization (you can [edit] this post).

Comment: The mistake was simple. The username and password were added to url and sent. Now I found a solution proposed by Salesforce - Named Credentials service. Now I'm trying to write apex code that can create Named Credential instance via metadata api. Thanks